# How to reference global property in setup script?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I'm trying to execute setup script in a test case and prepare some data.
I've defined connection, user & password in global properties, see:
[image]

Now I'd like to instead of hard coding connection, user and password to reference global property, is that possible?

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
def jdbcDriver = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver(jdbcDriver)
def jdbcConnection = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/mydb"
def jdbcConnectionUser="dbuser"
def jdbcConnectionPassword="dbpswrd"
log.info jdbcConnection
//log.info ${#Global#JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING} <-- this doesn't work ??
//${#Global#JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING}, ${#Global#DBUSER}, ${#Global#DBPASS}
def db = [url:jdbcConnection,user:jdbcConnectionUser,password:jdbcConnectionPassword,driver:jdbcDriver]
try
{
    def connection = Sql.newInstance(db.url, db.user, db.password, db.driver)
    context.setProperty("dbconn",connection)
    log.info "connected to the database"
}catch(Exception e){
    log.error "Could not connect to the database"
}
if(context.dbconn)
{
    def sql = context.dbconn    
    log.info "executing setup script"
    sql.execute "update table_a set column_b = 'S'  where column_c = 'something'"
    sql.close()
}
```

I've tried referencing global property using following syntax but to no avail

```
${#Global#JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to be working, should have read documentation before asking the question.

```
def jdbcConnection = com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.getPropertyValue( "JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING" )
def jdbcConnectionUser= com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.getPropertyValue("DBUSER")
def jdbcConnectionPassword= com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.getPropertyValue("DBPASS")
```

And here is a link where I found the answer and relevant excerpt :

```
def globalProperty = com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.getPropertyValue( "MyProp" )
```

https://www.soapui.org/scripting-properties/tips-tricks.html#1-2-Get-and-Set-Settings